# Java's FutureTask composability

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I try to work with Java's `FutureTask`, `Future`, `Runnable`, `Callable` and `ExecutorService` types.

What is the best practice to compose those building blocks?

Given that I have multiple `FutureTask`s and and I want to execute them in sequence.

Ofcourse I could make another FutureTask which is submitting / waiting for result for each subtask in sequence, but I want to avoid blocking calls.

Another option would be to let those subtasks invoke a callback when they complete, and schedule the next task in the callback. But going that route, how to I create a proper outer FutureTask object which also handles exceptions in the subtask without producing that much of a boilerplate?

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very important thing, though usually not described in tutorials:

`Runnables to be executed on an ExecutorService should not block`. This is because each blocking switches off a working thread, and if ExecutorService has limited number of working threads, there is a risk to fall into deadlock (thread starvation), and if ExecutorService has unlimited number of working threads, then there is a risk to run out of memory. Blocking operations in the tasks simply destroy all advantages of ExecutorService, so use blocking operations on usual threads only.

`FutureTask.get()` is blocking operation, so can be used on ordinary threads and not from an ExecutorService task. That is, it cannot serve as a building block, but only to deliver result of execution to the master thread.

Right approach to build execution from tasks is to start next task when all input data for the next task is ready, so that the task do not have to block waiting for input data. So you need a kind of a gate which stores intermediate results and starts new task when all arguments have arrived. Thus tasks do not bother explicitly to start other tasks. So a gate, which consists of input sockets for arguments and a Runnable to compute them, can be considered as a right building block for computations on ExcutorServices.

This approach is called dataflow or workflow (if gates cannot be created dynamically).

Actor frameworks like Akka use this approach but are limited in the fact that an actor is a gate with single input socket.

I have written a true dataflow library published at https://github.com/rfqu/df4j.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. It basically points out my problem very well. The thing is if you have some sort of task you want to reuse, then the logic what to do after cannot be included in that task and the Future interface is missing async callbacks. I recently came across https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained which also tries to solve this. But I usually want to find out how its meant to work, and basically, if i do not assume they did not think about this designing the interfaces, I still dont get it.

Comment: The best way to thank is to upvote the answer. Df4j has several kinds of building blocks, including `CallbackPromise` which is close to guava's `ForwardingCheckedFuture`. If you'll find that some other kinds of building blocks are worth to include in the library, simply file an issue at https://github.com/rfqu/df4j/issues

Comment: You seem misinformed, Akka dataflow does not use actors: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/dataflow.html, Akka Futures (now in Scala Standard Library, doesn't use Actors either: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/futures.html)

Comment: @Viktor Klang Akka is a huge framework, mainly built around actor concept. It does not use scala native actors, but heavily uses its own variant of actor system. The google query `actor site:http://doc.akka.io` yields >3000 answers, e.g. `http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0-RC2/general/actor-systems.html`. Probably `Akka dataflow` is a small subset which does not use actors, but I meant Akka as a whole.

Comment: I don't see how that factors in here at all. Akka Dataflow does not use Actors and is very lightweight, in fact, it's a single sourcefile with ~100 lines (mostly docs) and only needs Scala: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-dataflow/src/main/scala/akka/dataflow/package.scala

Comment: I also cannot see how `Akka dataflow` relates to the question. Using scala on Android is possible but requires considerable efforts, hardly justified in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar with a ScheduledFuture, trying to cause a delay before things were displayed to the user. This is what I come up with, simply use the same ScheduledFuture for all your 'delays'. The code was:

```
    public static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public ScheduledFuture delay = null;

    delay = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    //do something
    }
    }, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    delay = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    //do something else
    }
    }, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Hope this helps
Andy

Comment: Note that the ScheduledFuture can be cancelled before execution of its Runnable. In the example you will not be able to cancel the first job (other than by getting it from the scheduler’s queue).

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Just out of interest, would the above example work as intended if I had two ScheduledFuture's delay1 and delay2?

Comment: With the first call, the scheduler will wrap the runnable into a future, put that in it's task queue and return it to the calling thread. It does not matter to the scheduler, if you actually put it into a variable or not. So keeping the future is only for cancelling later or query the time to execution with getDelay.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to:

- Decide about ExecutorService (which type, how many threads).
- Decide about the task queue (for how long it could be non-blocking).

If you have some external code that waits for the task result:
* Submit tasks as Callables (this is non blocking as long as you do not run out of the queue).
* Call get on the Future.

If you want some actions to be taken automatically after the task is finished:

- You can submit as Callables or Runnables.
- Just add that you need to do at the end as the last code inside the task. Use 
  Activity.runOnUIThread these final actions need to modify GUI.

Normally, you should not actively check when you can submit one more task or schedule callback in order just to submit them. The thread queue (blocking, if preferred) will handle this for you.